# Server Login programme

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, server

so, I made my own little server. I tried to make it so, that you have to Login in order to access its files. I tried Javascript, but of course that is the worst thing to do (because you can see the passwords and usernames in the source code):

```
<form name="login">
Användar: <input type="text" name="user" value="gast">
<br>
Lösenord: <input type="password" name="pw" value="">
<br>
<input type="button" OnClick="log()" value="Login">
</form>
```

and the log() method:

```
function log() {

if (document.login.user.value == "gast")
if (document.login.pw.value == "0000")
location.href="gast.html"
}
```

So, this is cleary not a good way to do it, if you actually want it to be somewhat secure... So does anybody have an idea how I could do this? With a databank perhaps? I'm pretty much a beginner with HTML and JS, so some help would be great :)

Comment: If you have no other option than using javascript, you can always "hash" the password that the user enters and compare it to the stored password that is already hashed using the same method. See [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html) for example.

Comment: Hey thanks... I think about trying to combine your method plus IFun's to try it out... :)

Answer (score 3):

You should do authentication and authorization on the server-side.

I assume, you have a webserver running. Behind this webserver you have an application-interface, where the requests to your webserver are put forth to your application. This is  the "place" where you should do your auth-processing.

And whatever language you use to write your server-side application, I am sure there are already libraries that help you in that task. Proper authentication and authorization can be tricky, and there is no need to reinvent the wheel (unless of course there is a good reason to do so...).

Just google for "{your-language} authentication" or "{your-language} Framework authentication", where {your-language} is the programming language, you want to use on the server-side.

Anyhow, if you have no need for a full application, and just want to serve plain websites, you webserver should have a method for "Basic-Authentication". Again, just google for: "{your-webserver} Basic Authentication".

Comment: Thank you! I know got two methods to do it and I will definetly try yours as well, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Any login system needs to be serverside. Javascript is clientside. But there are many options depending on your server.

If you only have HTML and JS in your toolbox I'd look at using .htaccess if you are on a linux based server.

Comment: I'm using Apache 2 as my Server... would that work?

Comment: Yes that should support .htaccess files just fine. THere are a lot of tools online to help generate htaccess files. One example is here: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/

Comment: I also found [this](http://webdesignskolan.se/html/htaccess/htaccess_password.php) little tutorial... But thank you :) I will try that out later

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery. Its very easy, but verification through javascript is very dangerous and easy to challenge. I recommend to use PHP

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    var user = $("input[type='text']").val();
    var pass = $("input[type='password']").val();

    if (user === "gast" && pass === "0000") {
      location.href = "gast.html";
    } else {
      alert("bad password!");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="login">
  Användar:
  <input type="text" name="user" value="gast">
  <br>Lösenord:
  <input type="password" name="pw" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Login">
</form>
```

[**EXAMPLE1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/ef2yt6fm/)

---

---

when you must use javaScript, I recommend use Javascript Obfuscator: [**Javascript Obfuscator**](http://www.jsobfuscate.com/index.php) It's safer:

```js
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('$(12).13(4(){$("1[0=\'11\']").9(4(){6 7=$("1[0=\'14\']").3();6 5=$("1[0=\'2\']").3();18(7==="8"&&5==="20"){17.16="8.19"}15{21("10 2!")}})});',10,22,'type|input|password|val|function|pass|var|user|gast|click|bad|button|document|ready|text|else|href|location|if|html|0000|alert'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="login">
  Användar:
  <input type="text" name="user" value="gast">
  <br>Lösenord:
  <input type="password" name="pw" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Login">
</form>
```

[**EXAMPLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/ef2yt6fm/1/)

Comment: You "can" do that, but it does not mean you "should" do authentication with javascript.

Comment: @maze-le You're right, verification through javascript is very dangerous and easy to challenge. I recommend to use PHP

Comment: Hm... Thank you! I will definetly try out your method as well and combine it with the one by Niddro (to make the password to a hash and store it that way). Thanks :)

Comment: @IFun ... I have one question left about the Second Example. The obfuscated code. Is that basically Javascript made a little more unreadable? So, I can just put my log method into the obfuscator and paste the result into my login.js?

Comment: @MarvinJohanning Exactly. Is that basically Javascript, but unreadable... I use it when I do not want my code is easy to read