# Javascript Password Protected area.. must be better way

Tags: javascript, password-protection

I am still pretty fresh in the javascript scene, but I have this bit of code that works as intended for all intents and purposes.. but there just simply must be a better and cleaner way of going about it, and I would just love to see how it would be accomplished.

```
function Restricted() {

var password = 'pass1';
var password1 = 'pass2';
var password2 = 'pass3';
var password3 = 'pass4';
var password4 = 'pass5';

if (this.document.login.pass.value == password || this.document.login.pass.value == password1 || this.document.login.pass.value == password2 || this.document.login.pass.value == password3 || this.document.login.pass.value == password4) {

//Do stuff if correct

setTimeout(function() {
setLocation('#'); 
  }, 2000);
}
else {

//Alert them its wrong

}
```

so as you can see.. inputing all the different passwords is fine and to be expected, but the whole checking function of just comparing all the different passwords against eachother to tell if they work must be one of the worst ways of working around this.. haha, it's almost embarrassing as I look at it.

Comment: Don't do password validation on the front-end, any user can edit Javascript on their end as they please and gain access to what ever it is you're working on.

Comment: What's to prevent your users looking at the javascript and seeing the passwords?

Comment: or simply disable JS on your site?

Comment: That's why you never save passwords, but encrypt them.

Comment: @Andrew You don't encrypt passwords, you hash them.

Comment: And you don't send the hash to the client...

Comment: I answered a similiar querstion a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476598/server-login-programme/28476882#28476882

Comment: @Madara Uchiha encrypt and and then hash them :)

Comment: @Andrew Pointless. You don't add any bits of entropy like that, and you only make it harder for you to compare passwords. Just hashing is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the words guys! I'll look into other alternatives. I was naive enough to think just restricting right click access and obfuscation, among other menial things would be enough to deter the enemy. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your passwords in array and then use indexOf method of array. It returns index of the element in array or -1 if not present.

```
...
var passwords = ["pass1", "pass2"];
if (passwords.indexOf(this.document.login.pass.value) !== -1) {
...
```

However comparing passwords in JavaScript **is not a safe way** to do that, everybody can see the code or change it.

Answer (score 3):

Implement your login server-side. Your server should decide whether or not a user is trustworthy (by inputting a known pair of credentials) and if they are, allow access to restricted parts of the website.

If the user hasn't inputted the proper credentials yet and has no proper session/cookie to prove it, the server should deny entry.

Look up how to implement a simple login/authentication system in your favorite server-side language (PHP, NodeJS, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer a more general question as to not get involved in the much more important question about password validation on the client...oye. The general question is: Given a list of strings how do you match one?

The first thing is to take that list of strings (passwords) and put them into an array. And then you can match for an index using built-in array methods such as [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
function Restricted() {
  var strings = ['pass1', 'pass2', 'pass3', 'pass4', 'pass5'];

  if (strings.indexOf(this.document.login.pass.value) !== -1) {
    //Do stuff if correct
    setTimeout(function() {
      setLocation('#');
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    //Alert them its wrong
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect for the problem at hand, now to deal with the other areas of the issue.. thanks!

Comment: The indexOf method returns -1 if the array does not contain the string. However -1 is treated as true so this solution cannot work. Furthermore, if you enter password 'pass1' which is at index 0 it will be treated as false and evaluated as a wrong password.